# QLineEdit password safety

Tags: qt, passwords

In my application user types his password in `QLineEdit`.
`QLineEdit` works in Password echo mode.

Application must clear password from memory when it is no longer needed.

Does `QLineEdit` make sure that it clears all its internal memory buffers before they are freed? I cannot found such information in documentation.

If `QLineEdit` does not clear its content then what is the simplest way to implement such behavior? I want to reuse `QLineEdit` functionality as much as possible and do not want to implement my own password edit control from scratch. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Note that even when calling `setText({})` is not completely safe - the string might get written to swap space if your application is swapped out. The only way to prevent that is to allocate the memory for the internal string of the `lineEdit` yourself and call `mlock()` on it to prevent swapping. For that you need to write your own `lineEdit`.

In addition, the text is quite trivial to figure out when attaching a run-time introspection tool like [Gammaray](http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/gammaray/) to your application, as it is a normal `QObject` property, and stored obfuscated in RAM.

Also, by looking at the implementation of `QWidgetLineControl::internalSetText` (see [the code](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp.html#_ZN18QWidgetLineControl15internalSetTextERK7QStringib)), it seems like the line edit text is made available for the accessibility interface, which is accessible to everyone unless accessibility support was not compiled into Qt.

So, depending on your security level, you do need your own implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I think calling

```
QLineEdit::setText("");
```

will do the job. As Qt [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop) says:

> Setting this property clears the selection, clears the undo/redo
>   history, moves the cursor to the end of the line and resets the
>   modified property to false.

In opposite, calling `QLineEdit::clear()` will clear only text, however Undo/Redo stack will still contain the previous text.

Comment: Even though the internal string representation is ``free()``'d, that does not mean the string is overwritten. A deallocation usually does not overwrite the memory, so the string will still be available even after calling ``setText({})``. At the minimum do a ``setText("AAAAAAAAAA...")`` before that.