# QLineEdit password obfuscation

Tags: qt, password-protection, qlineedit

I am trying to implement a Login process with QT, and I'm curious about the safety of the `QLineEdit` widget. As I have seen online it seems that password remains stored even when `QLineEdit` is destroyed. Does overwriting with `QLineEdit::setText("mplampla");` solve the problem, or is the previous value kept somewhere?

Comment: What are you trying to protect? What do you mean with stored? in RAM? Any sources?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `echoMode()` to `Password`? It makes the `QLineEdit` *write-only*. Also can you point a source that states what you are quoting in your post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QLineEdit password safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048081/qlineedit-password-safety)

Comment: @rbaleksandar the post is actually from the link you provided, it is in fact the first answer. I specifically asked this cause I lack the points to comment my question below Thomas's answer...